# Copying data from one table in SQL

Tags: sql, join, subquery, using

I need to update an attribute by copying info from another table. The only problem is to identify the information needed I have to basically follow this format. 
update the charter table by
 setting the char_wait_chg equal to the results of
  selecting the mod_wait_chg from model and aircraft by matching
   mod_code between model and aircraft tables and
    ac_number between aircraft and charter tables.
I have a Charter table which contains AC_Number and CHAR_WAIT_CHG, the Aircraft table contains AC_Number and MOD_CODE, the Model table contains MOD_CODE and MOD_WAIT_CHG. I need to make CHAR_WAIT_CHG equal to MOD_WAIT_CHG, I thought I could use a subquery, but I get the error  ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row. Here is what I have tried:

```
    UPDATE CHARTER 
    SET CHAR_TOT_CHG=(SELECT MOD_WAIT_CHG FROM MODEL JOIN AIRCRAFT USING(MOD_CODE) JOIN CHARTER USING(AC_NUMBER));
```

I hope I explained this well enough, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query.  The subquery is returning more than one row:

```
UPDATE CHARTER 
    SET CHAR_TOT_CHG = (SELECT MOD_WAIT_CHG
                        FROM MODEL JOIN
                             AIRCRAFT
                             USING(MOD_CODE) JOIN
                             CHARTER
                             USING(AC_NUMBER)
                       );
```

You have to decide how you want to convert this to one row.

First possibility is that the subquery is wrong (because it is returning all the rows from the three tables).

If you really don't mean to have a different copy of the `charter` in the subquery, then make it a correlated subquery so you are no returning all rows in all the tables:

```
UPDATE CHARTER 
    SET CHAR_TOT_CHG = (SELECT MOD_WAIT_CHG
                        FROM MODEL JOIN
                             AIRCRAFT
                             USING(MOD_CODE)
                        where charter.ac_number = aircraft.ac_number
                       );
```

That might or might not fix the problem.  You could still have duplicates and you have to decide what to do with them.

If an arbitrary row is ok, then add:

```
where rownum = 1
```

If you want the `min()`/`max()`/`sum()`/`avg()` of the value, then use:

```
    SET CHAR_TOT_CHG = (SELECT sum(MOD_WAIT_CHG) . . .
```

If it shouldn't be returning duplicates, then investigate the data some more.